# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when variable is declared in class level

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Sometimes get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I declare a variable in class level, and use that variable in a procedure.

For example, this is my latest project to create a program to display the state of substances in a specific temperature:

```
 Public Class Form1
   Const WATER_FP As Integer = 0
   Const WATER_BP As Integer = 100

   Const ETHANOL_FP As Integer = -114
   Const ETHANOL_BP As Integer = 78

   Const MERCURY_FP As Integer = -39
   Const MERCURY_BP As Integer = 357

   Const OXYGEN_FP As Integer = -219
    Const OXYGEN_BP As Integer = -183

    Dim strSolid As String = vbNullString
    Dim strGas As String = vbNullString
    Dim sngTemperature As Single = CSng(txtTemperature.Text)

   Private Sub btnDisplayState_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayState.Click


      If sngTemperature <= WATER_FP Then
         strSolid &= "Water "
      ElseIf sngTemperature >= WATER_BP Then
         strGas &= "Water "
      End If

      If sngTemperature <= ETHANOL_FP Then
         strSolid &= "Ethanol "
      ElseIf sngTemperature >= ETHANOL_BP Then
         strGas &= "Ethanol "
      End If

      If sngTemperature <= MERCURY_FP Then
         strSolid &= "Mercury "
      ElseIf sngTemperature >= MERCURY_BP Then
         strGas &= "Mercury "
      End If

      If sngTemperature <= OXYGEN_FP Then
         strSolid &= "Oxygen "
      ElseIf sngTemperature >= OXYGEN_BP Then
         strGas &= "Oxygen "
      End If

      If strSolid <> vbNullString Then
         strSolid = "Substances that are in solid state are " & strSolid
      Else
         strSolid = "No substances are in solid state."
      End If

      If strGas <> vbNullString Then
         strGas = "Substances that are in gaseous state are " & strGas
      Else
         strGas = "No substances are in gaseous state."
      End If

      lblMessage.Text = strSolid & ControlChars.CrLf & strGas
   End Sub
End Class
```

Upon debugging, I get an error as described above, without any highlight of where the code is causing the problem. However, if I move the variables into `btnDisplayState_Click`, the program works perfectly. Now I know what caused the error, but furthermore I wanted to know why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare variable with a control's property as the control has not been initialized yet. You need to set the value after some text has been entered not before there is a value.

```
 Dim sngTemperature As Single = CSng(txtTemperature.Text)'no value here yet
```

Just declare it class level:

```
 Dim sngTemperature As Single
```

Then set it in the button event.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sngTemperature As Single = CSng(txtTemperature.Text)
```

Don't assign variables like that. You're assuming txtTemperature.Text is initialised BEFORE sngTempearature. Easy fix, change to:

```
Dim sngTemperature As Single = 0
```

and change your method to begin with:

```
Private Sub btnDisplayState_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayState.Click

  sngTemperature = CSng(txtTemperature.Text)

  If sngTemperature <= WATER_FP Then
     strSolid &= "Water "
  ' etc etc
```